# How should I fill out the Apple App Privacy in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, app-store-connect, privacy

I'm about to publish my ios app to the App Store, but I don't know how I should fill out the [Apple App Privacy](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/) in App Store Connect. I use admob, firebase analytics, firebase crashlytics and firebase authentication in my app. I've found this [website](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/filling-out-the-app-privacy-section-in-app-store-connect-for-admob-users-bca0768ad86e) that shows how to fill out the app privacy for admob, but I couldn't find one for firebase analytics or firebase crashlytics.

Do you know any website or tutorial that shows how to do fill out the app privacy for firebase analytics and firebase crashlytics? or if you've published an app to the App Store, can you tell me how you do it for your app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is up to which Third Party library you will intend to use. For instance, I bring together screenshots of how you will proceed to visualize the process in your mind.

From left to right; turn by turn you will see these screens. Also, you should be selected Analytics tick at the third screen if you have map functions related to Crashlytics.

[Managing App Privacy Apple Document](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1b4647c5b) and
[Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/app-store-data-collection)

[image]

Comment: Saved me! I also use Firebase and Crashlytics in the app. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Google has published documentation to help you navigate the Apple's App privacy. They describe what they collect and why. For firebase analytics check [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10285841) and for firebase crashlytics (and others) check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/app-store-data-collection)