# I cannot submit new build because of this error NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key in the binary (App Store)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, app-store

I have a flutter app, all I am doing is getting the user's current location. That's pretty simple by asking location permission with NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

But when I run the app, it crashes for missing key NSUserTrackingUsageDescription. When I added that Tracking Usage key now the app store is asking for which data I track (before submission), look at the error

> Your app contains NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, indicating that you will request permission to track users. To update this information on your app's product page, you must indicate which data types are tracking users. If this is incorrect, update your app binary and upload a new build to App Store Connect.

I need a location for address only when I provide that information, the continue button is still disabled. This app was published before 2-3 times but now I am having this issue. Now I am updating the App Privacy section about data but it seems the continue button is still disabled for me. I attached the screenshots.

[image: First Screenshot]

[image: Second Screenshot]

Comment: i just answered a few days ago, this answer is related your question ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/65454902/14531220

Comment: You are right, But its still not working for me.

Comment: ok if u upvote i will be appreciated and now trying to find a new solution for you

Comment: Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67083153/8342742)?

Answer (score 3):

Same issue was encountered in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207375/nsusertrackingdescription-failure). I suggest to follow the same workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69622704):

> To address this issue go to `App Store Connect` > `App Privacy`:
>
> 1- under `Data Types` > `Location` > I selected `Precise Location` >
> `Next` > `Save`
>
> 2-under the gray Location/Precise Location Section (pictured below)
> press the blue **Edit Button** and tick these 3 selections:
>
> • **Used for App Functionality**
>
> • **Linked to the user's identity**
>
> • **Used for tracking purposes** this is the last option, you must
> tick *Yes, we use precise location data for tracking purposes*. This
> will make the error go away
>
> [image]
>
> Now the Location section it looks likes this and the error went away