# Unable disable tracking in the App Privacy section in App Store Connect due to NSUserTrackingUsageDescription?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apptrackingtransparency

I have added App Tracking Transparency in a previous build, I would now like to remove it as I am no longer doing tracking. I've removed the `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` key from the Info.plist but I still can't remove tracking from the App Privacy section on App Store Connect, I get this error:

> Your app contains NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, indicating that you will request permission to track users. To update this information on your app's product page, you must indicate which data types are tracking users. If this is incorrect, update your app binary and upload a new build to App Store Connect.

I've tried submitting the app with App Privacy->Tracking enabled but without requesting ATT. Apple respond with

> The app privacy information you provided in App Store Connect indicates you collect data in order to track the user, including Product Interaction. However, you do not use App Tracking Transparency to request the user's permission before tracking their activity.

I've tried explaining this issue to Apple but they respond generically and don't acknowledge this must be an issue on their end. Probably the reviewer is blocked by a computer-says-no situation? Unless I'm missing something, all I have to do is remove `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` from Info.plist and I should be able to disable the tracking configuration in the app privacy section in App Store Connect?

I suspect this is a caching bug on App Store Connect, so I've tried uploading multiple builds. I've also tried re-enabling ATT so that we get a build accepted, then re-disabling ATT in a subsequent build but the above error message is still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple’s error relating to `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` was misleading as this wasn’t why our app was being rejected.

Removing `AppsFlyer` solved our issue. Likely Apple were doing a basic grep in the app binary for the term `AppTrackingTransparency`.

Answer (score 1):

It did happen to me lately.

My app's current live version does use `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` but new submission doesn't.

My new submission was rejected 8 times during the review. I double checked everything on my project thinking that there might be some dependency which adds/references `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` or in localized string file. But I didn't find anything. Then I'm sure the problem isn't in my code. But Apple review team kept insisting me with the following message:

> Hello,
>
> The issues we previously identified still need your attention.
>
> If you have any questions, we are here to help. Reply to this message
> in App Store Connect and let us know.
>
> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> We noticed your app's binary contains references to App Tracking
> Transparency, but you have indicated you do not intend to ask users
> for permission to track at this time.
>
> Since App Tracking Transparency is only intended to be used by apps
> requesting authorization to track, it would be appropriate to disable
> App Tracking Transparency before resubmitting your app for review.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, remove any App Tracking Transparency-related
> keys in your app's info.plist and from localized string files.
>
> In addition to removing these keys, you may also choose to fully
> remove other references to the AppTrackingTransparency framework from
> your app.
>
> If your app does not track users, update your app privacy information
> in App Store Connect to not declare tracking. You must have the
> Account Holder or Admin role to update app privacy information.

So I did choose to appeal to App Review Board by explaining my situation. Finally my app was approved today! (after 28 days in review)

Here is the related threads:

- Cannot remove App Privacy after removing AdMob and tracking - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679585?answerId=686370022#686370022
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953211/14546446